# Небольшое изменение в Function

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Только-что возникла одна гениальная идея.. Но для этого мне нужно знать:

Возможно ли "поколдовать" с объектом Function так, чтоб при вызове неинициализированных функций происходил вызов какой-то функции?

Comment: Эээ... Можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ваша гениальная идея предполагает возможность наличия в коде вызова функции, которая не определена, то вам стоит пересмотреть свои приоритеты в жизни. JavaScript не типизирован, позволяет всячески пренебрегать правилами, но магию творить вне Хогвартса запрещено!

Вы можете обработать вызов функции, которой нет

```js
function someFunction() {
  console.log("2+2 =", 2 + 2)
}

try {
  asd()
} catch (e) {
  if (e.message.indexOf('is not defined') > 0) {
    someFunction()
  }
}
```

При вызове `asd` выкинется `ReferenceError`, который можно поймать и вызвать другую функцию

Можно объявить функцию перед выполнением или выполнить только если функция определена

```js
// Определим до вызова
if (typeof myFunc !== "function") {
  function myFunc() {
    console.log("2+2 =", 2 + 2)
  }
}
myFunc()

// Проверим до вызова
if (typeof myFunc == "function") myFunc()
```

Comment: второй пример не сработает в strict mode